# Wrong device height and width on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the screen resolution of mobile phones in my Ionic app using `platform.width()` and  `platform.height()`.

Testing it with a One Plus One (1080x1920 pixels), it gives me 360x640.
Visiting [this website](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com) with the phone gives the same values.

What's going on here? Is this normal behavior? I would think `window.innerWidth()` and `.innerHeight()` would work on mobile phone too.

Comment: did you try `screen.width` and `screen.height`?

Comment: Yes I have. Same (wrong) value...

Comment: did you try with a different device? or on browser? also try to console.log window.screen object.

Comment: also try to console.log or alert the screen.width in the device ready event, tell me if its still wrong

Comment: Yes, I've tried 2 devices, alert and console log. Same result every time.

Comment: i want you to just `console.log(screen.height)` on the deviceready event, do you still get the wrong values?

Comment: also try to show us more code